# GCD Using Euclidean Algorithm

Tags: divisibility

How do I find the GCD of $65024$ and $128397$?
And how do I express the GCD as a linear combination of $65024$ and $128397$ of the form $g = a\cdot 65024 + b\cdot 128397$?

**My work:**

$128397 = 65024\cdot 1 + 63373$

$65024 = 63373\cdot 1 + 1651$

$63373 = 1651\cdot 38 + 635$

$1651 = 635\cdot 2 + 381$

$635 = 381\cdot 1 + 254$

$381 = 254\cdot 1 + 127$

$254 = 127\cdot 2 + 0$

Thus, the GCD is $127$.

Comment: I found the GCD to be $127$, but I don't know how to do it using the algorithm.

Comment: Is this how you do it? 128397 = 65024*1 + 63373
 65024 = 63373*1 + 1651
 63373 = 1651*38 + 635
 1651 = 635*2 + 381
 635 = 381*1 + 254
 381 = 254*1 + 127
 254 = 127*2 + 0

Comment: Okay so you found the $gcd$ to be $127$. How did you find this? By using the Euclidean algorithm right? You want to sort of reverse the process (using substitution) to obtain the linear combination you are looking for.

Comment: @induktio Is my process to find the GCD okay, above?

Comment: Did you try working it backwards as mathtastic suggested in his answer?

Comment: @induktio I am doing it right now to find the linear combination, but is my work for GCD correct as shown above?

Comment: See my answer below. It details how you can use your first work to come up with the linear combination you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you got the $\mathrm{gcd}$ is fine. But as people have pointed out, you want to work *backward* to get your answer. Consider the following:
\begin{align}
127 &= 381-254\\[0.5em]
    &= 381-[635-381]=2\cdot 381-635\\[0.5em]
    &= 2[1651-2\cdot 635]-635 = 2\cdot 1651-5\cdot 635\\[0.5em]
    &= 2\cdot 1651-5[63373-38\cdot 1651]=192\cdot 1651-5\cdot 63373\\[0.5em]
    &= 192[65024-63373]-5\cdot 63373=192\cdot 65024-197\cdot 128397\\[0.5em]
    &= 192\cdot 65024-197[128397-65024]=389\cdot 65024-197\cdot 128397
\end{align}
Thus, we have that 
$$
127=389\cdot 65025+(-197)\cdot 128397.
$$
This is your linear combination. So you have $g=65025a+128397b$, where $g=127,a=389,b=-197$.

Is that clear?

Comment: Yes, Thank You!

Comment: @fibonacci Yeah and welcome to MSE! In the future, try to write up your questions by following the guidelines outlined here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

$gcd(a,b)$ with $a \ge b$:

$$a=q_0b+r_0$$
   $$ b = q_1 r_0 + r_1$$
    $$r0 = q_2 r_1 + r_2$$
    $$r1 = q_3 r_2 + r_3$$
$$...$$

Where the last remained term $r_n=gcd(a,b)$

And for $ax+by=c$

you work your way backward through this process, substituting 'upward' until you can express $c=ax+by$

Comment: Can you see if I am correct?